# Mathematical proof of $dW = p dV$ for arbitrary shapes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

**Note:** As it stands this is a mathematical question, and not really about physics. I want to know about the setting up of a certain integral and showing that it equals $p dV$.

As is well known, the First Law of Thermodynamics is given by $$dU = dQ - p dV$$

Here $dU$ is an exact differential form, whereas both $dQ$ and $p dV$ aren't. In elementary texts, the infinitesimal work done by a gas enclosed in a cylindrical piston is calculated as $dW = p dV$. In only two books (one by Fermi, and another by Sommerfeld) are sketches of proof given for a gas enclosed in a container with any shape whatsoever.

The sketches given are not exactly mathematically rigorous. There are suggestions that a surface integral should be computed, but I can't seem to formulate it in terms of vector calculus or differential forms.

In fact this question has been raised before (and the corresponding passage in Fermi included, see here : [How can this result in Thermodynamics be rigorously proved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516901/how-can-this-result-in-thermodynamics-be-rigorously-proved)), but so far there doesn't seem to be any satisfactory answer.

I would like to know how this is done in a mathematically precise way.

Comment: The 1st law of Thermodynamics is $dU = dQ - dW$. Expressing $dW = PdV$ applies only to systems where the work is done by a pressure $P$ acting on or produced by a changing volume $V$. There are other ways of doing work on systems where this expression does not apply.